# Product of holomorphic and antiholomorphic functions

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Let $f = u + iv$ be holomorphic and $g= w + il$ be antiholomorphic (that is $w -il$ is holomorphic) in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$. What can we say about their product $f\cdot g$?

Comment: Do you have any particular properties in mind...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Holomorphic, antiholomorphic, analytic, harmonic, a polynomial, ...

Answer (score 1):

By considering $z \mapsto z \overline z$ you can see that you have no chances to have holomorphic, anti-holomorphic, harmonic or polynomial functions. You only have $C^{\infty}$ function since both holomorphic and anti-holomorphic functions are $C^{\infty}$.

Remark : If you consider $f(z) = \sum a_n z^n$ and $g(\overline z) = \sum b_n \overline z^n$ you can notice that the product $f(z)g(\overline z)$ is real analytic considered as a function of $(x,y)$. This is also $C^{\infty}$ as a function of $(z, \overline z)$ and you can't say anything more interesting in general.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "By considering $z \mapsto z \overline z$ you can see ..."?

Comment: $z \to z$ is holomorphic and $z \to \overline z$ is anti-holomorphic. And $z \overline z = |z|^2$ is not holomorphic, etc ... You can consider it as a "counter-example" to what you did expected in comments.

Comment: @Axel : I did put a little remark. I don't think you can say anything more in general.